# I can't clone a project

Tags: drush, acquia-dev-desktop, acquia-cloud

I have a locally multi-site. Locally Drush works perfectly fine. But When I try to clone this project in different machine I get this error in Acquia Dev Desktop:

[image: dev desktop]

I also tried to run a Drush command via SSH and get this error:

[image: cmd]

Is any configuration that I am missing?

Is there another way to update my DB with config files?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Is any configuration that I am missing?` Clearly your Drush is broken, fix your Drush... Looks like you have a permission issue; thus, your Drush is not able to execute. Read what errors are telling you???

Comment: Hi, I have read my errors and I also have search about, open ticket with acquia and ask for help to website/repo admin.
Didn't found any solution.
Admin said I have all permissions granted, acquia told me same thing I already know.
My problem is locally drush works fine and inside acquia cloud not and I dont have more ideas to set this working, thats why I came ask for help :)

Comment: I think you need *system* permission; run your command with `sudo` or modify your drush permissions to permit local file operations.

Comment: Hi, tried to run with sudo and ask me for a password, but I don't have permissions, also tried to change file permissions and got same permissions error.
If I change permissions locally this will affect my files on acquia cloud server?